# Model with 2 datasets: combine time series data and statistics

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, random-forest, beginner, ensemble-modeling

I am new to data science modelling so apologies if using wrong terminology in advance.

I have a standard time series dataset of historical prices which is used to train/test a simple Random Forest classifier model which predicts the returns direction (+/-).

I also have a few general statistics for 'day of the week direction' eg. frequency counts: Monday UP=120, Monday DOWN=90, Tuesday UP=67, Tuesday DOWN=50, Friday UP=55, Friday DOWN=181.

How can I combine the results from the time series RF model with the bias from the statistics into a new model? eg. give more weight to positive/up predictions on Monday, and more weight to negative/down predictions on Friday?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches. Two of them are:

- Convert time series data to structured data
- Convert your statistic data to time series data

[This article](https://medium.com/@dxiaochuan/combining-time-series-and-tabular-data-for-prediction-9815a5a17cd) is a good introduction.

For your second question about giving more weight to some features, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034702/how-to-put-more-weight-on-certain-features-in-machine-learning).

Hope it helps.